Quasar V2 PWA Mode Bad Precaching Error (404)
I am running my web app in PWA but I face the following error:
Uncaught (in promise) bad-precaching-response: bad-precaching-response :: [{"url":"https://myurl/index.html","status":404}]

Here's the quasar.config:
pwa: {
      workboxMode: 'generateSW', // or 'injectManifest'
      injectPwaMetaTags: true,
      swFilename: 'sw.js',
      manifestFilename: 'manifest.json',
      useCredentialsForManifestTag: false,
      // workboxOptions: {
      //   skipWaiting: true,
      //   clientsClaim: true,
      // },
      // useFilenameHashes: true,
      // extendGenerateSWOptions (cfg) {}
      // extendInjectManifestOptions (cfg) {},
      // extendManifestJson (json) {}
      // extendPWACustomSWConf (esbuildConf) {}
    },

And the custom-service-worker.ts:
import { clientsClaim } from 'workbox-core';
import {
  precacheAndRoute,
  cleanupOutdatedCaches,
} from 'workbox-precaching';

self.skipWaiting();
clientsClaim();

// Use with precache injection
precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST, {
  ignoreURLParametersMatching: [/^index.html/]
});

cleanupOutdatedCaches();

I use Vite.
I have tried different ways but got the same error.

The error says the file in the URL is not found (404). Make sure the manifest file is up to date and reflects the current file states. To locate the issue, exclude the URL and file from the cache, it may help.

how to exclude the URL and file from the cache?, that's what i'm trying to do but i can't fix it
